# Lightswitch, AJAX and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am preparing to demo Lightswitch to a group of about 100 software developers in a couple weeks and 
have run into a snag.

I have a VS2012 solution with two projects:

- Lightswitch - simple data model and ApplicationData.svc
- Web - contains a web page that attempts to communicate with the ApplicationData.svc using JQuery Ajax

My problem is when I try to run the solution and execute the AJAX command, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:37650/ApplicationData.svc/MyEntities.  Origin
http://localhost:53408 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

After googling around for a while, I found this advice, which looked promising:

```
<system.webServer> 
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

But it did not resolve the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This works only for IIS7, http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html maybe you have IIS6? Then you have to do it over the IIS Manager: http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been running into the same issue, only mine is that I am creating a HTML5 JQuery Mobile application that is NOT a web application. The app is JQuery based app that I am going to run through PhoneGap. My issue is that when I make the calls from the mobile app, I get the same cross domain issues.

What browser are you using to test? I am doing Chrome and I get the issue because of the initial Options request (see http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ ). I've tried a bunch of possible solutions, like updating config files and so on, but to no avail.

My next kick at the cat will be to intercept the initial Options request by creating an IHttpHandler that I can apply as an attribute to the WCF service I am using (did I mention that I created custom WCF services within the Server project in the LightSwitch solution?).

I'll keep you posted...

Paul

Comment: I was using Chrome to test. But, prompted by your question, I tried IE10. Works great :( I thought the Chrome problems had been taken care of before the final release. Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add:

```
headers: { "If-Match": " *" }
```

see:

A Full CRUD DataJs and KnockoutJs LightSwitch Example Using Only An .Html Page 
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/128/A-Full-CRUD-DataJs-and-KnockoutJs-LightSwitch-Example-Using-Only-An-Html-Page.aspx

Comment: No that's not it. It says XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:37650 but it says http://localhost:53408 is not allowed. Notice that the ports (37650 vs 53408) don't match. Each time you debug the ports change that the web server is using. You have to dynamically set the port when calling the website in your JQuery code. See the link that I posted for code that does this.

Comment: Michael - thanks for the response. The ports are correct. They are two separate web projects within the solution. I wanted to demo how to use Lightswitch to create the OData web service and then access it from another web app. This is a cross-domain problem. I just don't know how to solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with this:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="3600" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, MaxDataServiceVersion" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, MERGE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Which file did you put this in? Server\web.config? I tried that, pressed F5 to spin up the LS project and then pulled up my web page. Same problem.

Comment: Yes, i used this in Server\web.config and work for me. I dont know what will be the problem.